# Windows 10 Local group policy edit via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy

I tried to edit local group policy on Windows 10.

Steps:

1. I tried to change value for local group policy. `Local Group Policy Editor` Example: `Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/ Microsoft Defender Antivirus/Scan/ Name: "Scan archive files" Value "Enabled"`
2. Next, I go to Registry Editor and find path `"HKLM/Software/Policies/Microsoft/WindowsDefender/Scan"` and find `Disable Archive scanning` with value `0`
3. I tried to edit this value to `1` via GUI and PowerShell `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scan\" -Name DisableArchiveScanning -Value 1`. It value is changing for Registry Editor.
4. I run `gpupdate`
5. My policies do not changes.

What did I do wrong?

Is it possible to change policies via PowerShell?

UPDATED:

My target is change Local Group Policy remotely (best way via PowerShell). I found suggestion trying to change Registry Editor. Is it way to change Local group Policy remotely?

Also, I tried to change file  `C:/Windows/system32/GroupPolicy/Machine/Registry.pol`

Comment: Running `gpupdate` overwrites what you have changed in the registry. If you want to have that value persistent, change it in the local Group Policy Editor

Comment: My target is change Local Group Policy remotely (best way via PowerShell). I found suggestion trying to change Registry Editor. Is it way to change Local group Policy remotely?

Comment: Have a look at module [GroupPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer.
I can use [PolicyFileEditor](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PolicyFileEditor/3.0.0) and [related answer](https://serverfault.com/a/875919)
After run PolicyFileEditor command you should run `gpupdate` and new policy is applied. I checked it by trying edit setting established by policy and value did not changes if you try to correct it. Value can be changed if you change policy. But in Local Group Policy Editor you can not see parameters changes.

Comment: PolicyFileEditor is a scam. All it does is write to the registry, it does nothing to the actual policy, as I, and now you have witnessed in gpedit. If anyone can prove me wrong, I'd be grateful.